Generalization of Büchi-Elgot-Trakhtenbrot theorem
There is a well known correspondence between automata and languages (e.g. Chomsky heirarchy).
The Büchi-Elgot-Trakhtenbrot (BET) theorem characterizes regular languages as formalizable in monadic second order (MSO) logic. Presumably this also establishes a correspondence between MSO logic and finite automata, since they generate regular languages.
Is there a generalization of the BET theorem to recursively enumerable languages (hence presumably a correspondence between Turing machines and a particular type of logic)?

Yes there is. In https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.1715 the author introduced a Turing-complete logic which captures precisely the recursively enumerable languages.
Edit: the same author considers in https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.4080 a different, but closely related, Turing-complete logic. The basic idea is simple. First, we introduce a new operator $I$ which has the following semantics. Let $\varphi$ be a sentence (of same typical logic such as first-order logic or existential second-order logic), $Y$ a unary second-order variable and $\mathfrak{A}$ a $\tau$-structure. We define that $\mathfrak{A} \models IY \varphi$ iff there exists a finite set $U$ such that the following two conditions hold.

$\mathrm{dom}(\mathfrak{A}) \cap U = \varnothing$.
Let $\mathfrak{A}^+$ be the $(\tau \cup \{Y\})$-structure which has $ \mathrm{dom}(\mathfrak{A}) \cup U$ as its domain, $Y^{\mathfrak{A}^+} := U$ and $R^{\mathfrak{A}^+} := R^{\mathfrak{A}}$ for every $R \in \tau$. Now $\mathfrak{A}^+ \models \varphi$.

So basically $I$ just extends the domain of the underlying structure with a fresh finite set of elements. Now the logic consisting of sentences of the form $I\varphi$, where $\varphi$ is a sentence of existential second-order logic, is Turing complete.

neat. i'd be interested to see Kuusisto's construction brought closer to BET (i.e., using a superset of MSO). i also wonder if the game-theoretic semantics are necessary for the jump to RE?

@silly-little-guy I extended my post, hopefully answering your question.
